# Triangulation with 3 known points and time is involved?

Tags: trigonometry, triangulation

I am completely stuck on how to visualize this problem, let alone code it. Understanding the mathematics behind it could help me out a lot. Thanks!

Let's suppose that the unknown point is actually a point source for some
pollutant X, and at time 0 it releases a burst of X. Assume no wind, and that X
diffuses freely from its release point. Suppose that we have measurement devices at
the three points 1, 2, and 3 that track the concentration of X as a function of time,
and that the concentration of X is detected to peak at times t1
, t2, and t3, at each
point, respectively. Can we determine the location of the evil point source?

Comment: Can we assume the pollutant moves at a fixed speed in all directions from the point source?